# Why will multiple blocks not consistently float to the right of a higher inline-block?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to float multiple blocks to the right of a higher image/inline-block. This works fine in Chrome on bigger screen sizes. But it bugs out on smaller screens. In that case the blocks will display below the image/inline-block instead of on the right. It bugs out all the time in MS Edge.

Why does this happen? Notice that I am not looking for answers that "fix the issue", because I know a fix (in the second fiddle). **I just want to know why it behaves as it does and/or if I am doing something wrong here.**

It looks like: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftz9ffpk/1/)
I want it to display it like: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkqs5kjr/1/).

Code of the first example:

**html**

```
<header><div id="image"></div>
    <p>Welcome to XXX fdgfg dfg dfg df d</p>
    <p><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span> Filter</p>
    <p><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete</p>
    <p><span class='glyphicon-envelope'></span> New mail</p>
    <p><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-book'></span> Contacts</p>
    <p><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span> Settings</p>
</header>
```

**css**

```
header{
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(25,25,25);
}
#image{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  background-color: green;
}
header p{
    margin: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

Thx in advance

Comment: It doesn't work fine in Chrome for me. Is 1920x1080 enough, or does it need to be bigger?

Comment: @GolezTrol That is exactly my screensize. Did you try making the example screen in JS-Fiddle bigger?

Comment: @RMo If you are looking why text goes out of dark background then because of you are not using clear property. Try to use clear:both after p tag and text wont go outside without using your solution. It happens when you use float without using clear.